# How to return rows only where all supplied values are found in a mysql join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an inner join like this:

```sql
SELECT
    p.id
    , p.date
    , pu.user_id
FROM projections p
INNER JOIN projection_user AS pu ON p.id = pu.projection_id
WHERE pu.user_id IN ('1', '3')
```

This returns the following results:

```
id | date       | user_id 
--------------------------
16 | 2020-03-05 | 1
17 | 2020-03-05 | 1
17 | 2020-03-05 | 3
```

I would like to only return rows where the projection (`p.id`) has the exact `pu.user_id` values supplied in my `WHERE` clause -- in this case the projection with a `p.id` of 17, since it has both `pu.user_id` 1 and 3, and no others. In the full code I am actually grouping by `p.id` for the final result:

```sql
SELECT
    p.id
    , p.date
FROM projections p
INNER JOIN projection_user AS pu ON p.id = pu.projection_id
WHERE pu.user_id IN ('1', '3')
GROUP BY p.id
```

```
id | date
--------------------------
16 | 2020-03-05
17 | 2020-03-05
```

How can I only return the projection with `p.id` of 17?

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT p.id, p.date, GROUP_CONCAT(pu.user_id)
FROM projections p INNER JOIN
     projection_user pu
     ON p.id = pu.projection_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.date
HAVING SUM(pu.user_id IN (1, 3)) = COUNT(*) AND
       COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Note:  This assumes no duplicates in `projection_user`, which is typically a reasonable assumption.  The query can be tweaked if such duplicates are possible.

Or, if you prefer:

```
SELECT p.id, p.date,
       GROUP_CONCAT(pu.user_id ORDER BY pu.user_id) as user_ids
FROM projections p INNER JOIN
     projection_user pu
     ON p.id = pu.projection_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.date
HAVING user_ids = '1,3';
```

Comment: This returns both `p.id` 16 and 17 if I query for `pu.user_id IN (1, 2, 3)`, but I wouldn't want any to return in that case, since neither projection has ALL 1, 2 and 3 user_ids. I did modify your first query to include `AND COUNT(*) = 2` (where the 2 is computed programatically) and it seems to work perfectly. Is that the best way or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: @JordanWalker . . . You might  find the second method simpler to parameterize.

Answer (score 0):

This amendment to Gordon Linoff's answer works as needed:

```sql
SELECT
    p.id
    , p.date
FROM projections p
INNER JOIN projection_user AS pu ON p.id = pu.projection_id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING SUM(pu.user_id IN (1, 3)) = COUNT(*) AND COUNT(*) = 2
```